# How to export and import a variable amount to a json file to keep numbers after program ends

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dump

**This Problem has been solved.**

I have googled this many times, but can't seem to find out how to export a variable's data to a JSON file. I also am having problems importing them back and would like it if someone could point me to an article that would explain how to make the code that I have work. Here is the code:

```
bank_data={
    'name1': name1,
    'name2': name2,
    'name3': name3,
    'p1bal': p1bal,
    'p2bal': p2bal,
    'p3bal': p3bal,
    'namenumb': namenumb,
    'namepass1': namepass1,
    'namepass2': namepass2,
    'namepass3': namepass3,
}

json_string=json.dumps(bank_data)     
with open('bank_files.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_string)
```

if you would like to view the full program to see how this is being used, here is the link:
https://app.codingrooms.com/w/13hXi2nKIEZf

Thanks!
-TenseSnake9

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Did you try just ```json.dump(bank_data, outfile)``` instead of ```outfile.write(json_string)```?  Then to load the file, you use ```with open('bank_files.json', 'r') as outfile:   bank_data = json.load(outfile)```?

Comment: What you have here should correctly write the JSON to a file. You can also use `json.dump()` to do this more directly. To get the JSON data back into your program, use `json.load()`.

Comment: If you still need help, please explain what happens when you run your code, then describe what you want instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did do that, but what the file would keep the different variables blank, even if they had a value when exporting.

Comment: @ewong using what you suggested, where would I put the file that the dictionary bank_data would export to?

Comment: @TenseSnake9 You will have to show the code you wrote that loads the JSON file for us to help you. And you can store the file anywhere you'd like. Usually it's easiest to store it in the same file as the python script that uses it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If you would like to see the whole code, please click the link that is in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Questions should be self-contained so that 1) they will be understandable even if (when) external sites go down, 2) they don't require people to bounce around to multiple web pages, 3) so they are better indexed by search engines. While links to external resources can be helpful, they should only be in addition to, rather than instead of, information in the question.

Comment: See "[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527)", "[What to do with a coding challenge question where the problem statement is in an external link/page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367866/90527)", [mcve]

Comment: I am sorry @outis, but on another account, long lost, I got told that I shouldn't put all of my code in there because it was too long. I was trying to make it short and readable

Comment: @TenseSnake9: Hence a [mcve]. A link to code doesn't make things short & readable (as the code itself has the same length, wherever it's posted), it just adds extra steps. See the previous links. Please also consult the [help] articles, especially "[ask]".

Comment: Statements such as "This Problem has been solved" do not belong in a question; questions are marked as solved by accepting an answer. Note you can [self-answer](/help/self-answer) and then accept it, but you should still make your question clear enough on its own for others to understand (in this case, folks with similar questions looking to your posts for answers).

Comment: @TenseSnake9 I'm glad to hear you solved the problem. For future reference, you should create a [mcve] when asking a question. This is often a new python file completely separate from your project. It should only be enough code to illustrate the problem that you are asking about. No more. No less. Posting all of your code from your main project is never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. Thanks to everyone who helped. I achieved it by assigning the variable values to the values in the dictionary and vice versa.

```
name1=bank_data['name1']
name2=bank_data['name2']
name3=bank_data['name3']
p1bal=bank_data['p1bal']
p2bal=bank_data['p2bal']
p3bal=bank_data['p3bal']
namenumb=bank_data['namenumb']
namepass1=bank_data['namepass1']
namepass2=bank_data['namepass2']
namepass3=bank_data['namepass3']
```

As you can see here, I am defining the variables as the values of the elements from the dictionary bank_data that is imported from the bank_files.json file at the beginning of the code being run. In the end, I do the same thing but in reverse. I define the values in the dictionary based on the values of the variables and then export them to the file.

```
with open("bank_files.json") as json_file:
    bank_data=json.load(json_file)
bank_data['name1']= name1
bank_data['name2']= name2
bank_data['name3']= name3
bank_data['p1bal']= p1bal
bank_data['p2bal']= p2bal
bank_data['p3bal']= p3bal
bank_data['namenumb']= namenumb
bank_data['namepass1']= namepass1 
bank_data['namepass2']= namepass2
bank_data['namepass3']= namepass3
with open ('bank_files.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(bank_data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: What you typed here isn't really an answer. If you would like to share your solution, you should write it out completely .